# Multiple readmore buttons working at the same time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map-function

Good Morning.

I'm trying to use "readmore" buttons on texts coming from the firestore

```
<section className="escritos">
  {escritos.map(escrito => {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          Autor: <strong>{escrito.autor}</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          {" "}
          Título: <strong>{escrito.titulo}</strong>
        </p>
        <div id="obras">
          {" "}
          {readmore
            ? parse(escrito.escrito)
            : parse(escrito.escrito.substring(0, 200))}
          <button id="readmore" onClick={() => setReadmore(!readmore)}>
            {readmore ? "ler menos" : "ler mais"}
          </button>
          <Link to="#beginning">
            <BsFillArrowUpCircleFill />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
  })}
</section>
```

It's working. But it works at the same time for all buttons.

I've already tried to use [react-read-more](https://github.com/alexandersmanning/read-more-react), but there was an error because I have to use **parse(escrito.escrito)** to remove the html tags. Removing the parse, it works but with the tags showing.

It has something to do with the **map** I believe, but I haven't been able to solve it yet.

Here's the [site](https://www.meusescritos.com.br) and here's the [repository](https://github.com/jcgsr/jan-MeusEscritos) if it helps.

Thank you in advance for your attention and your time.

Comment: You should set key to the mapped elements. But im not sure if thats is going to slove the issue

Comment: Hey Ferran. I've just did following your suggestion and raqibrasheed's. But the buttons are still working at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the `readmore` state to be applied to the individual boxes you could store an array in the state and check, if the `id` is set, but I would go with the (in my opinion) simpler way:

Extract your block into its own component, which has its own state `readmore` like so:

```
<section className="escritos">
  {escritos.map(escrito => (
     <Escrito escrito={escrito} key={escrito.id} />
   ))}
</section>

// Escrito.jsx
const Escrito = ({escrito}) => {
    const [readmore, setReadmore] = useState(false);
    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          Autor: <strong>{escrito.autor}</strong>
        </p>
        <p>
          {" "}
          Título: <strong>{escrito.titulo}</strong>
        </p>
        <div id="obras">
          {" "}
          {readmore
            ? parse(escrito.escrito)
            : parse(escrito.escrito.substring(0, 200))}
          <button id="readmore" onClick={() => setReadmore(!readmore)}>
            {readmore ? "ler menos" : "ler mais"}
          </button>
          <Link to="#beginning">
            <BsFillArrowUpCircleFill />
          </Link>
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
    );
}

export default Escrito;
```

Since each component now has its own state, this should be the behavior you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Parent element returned from the `escritos.map(escrito => {JSX})` should contain a key attribute with unique value. Read more [here](https://meganslo.medium.com/why-is-reacts-key-prop-important-b6bd51124270)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and link. I've put the "key" prop as follows

`<section className="escritos">
          {escritos.map(escrito => {
            return (
              <div key={escrito.id}>
                <p>
                 ...
                    `

but the buttons are still working at the same time though.